# Cómo devolver el nombre de un objeto localStorage - JS

Tags: javascript, object, local-storage

Al guardar un objeto en localStorage, uso lo siguiente:

```
var shoppingCart = window.localStorage;
shoppingCart.setItem(item_name, item_string);
```

Luego, cuando recargo la página o quiero retornar el objeto, vuelvo a llamar al espacio Storage creado, o sea **shoppingCart**:

```
JSON.parse(shoppingCart.getItem(item_name))
```

Pero me indica que:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: shoppingCart is not defined
```

Y no me devuelve nada. Usando *Storage.getItem(...* sí funciona y devuelve.

Comment: solo por curiosidad cuando haces el refresh estas realizando esto? var shoppingCart = window.localStorage;?? al parecer te falta

Comment: O si quiera, ni al hacer refresh. Acabó de ejecutar la función y ya no conoce al objeto shoppingCart

Comment: Si `shoppingCart` lo declaras dentro de la función que mencionas, como dices, en cuanto termine la ejecución dicho objeto deja de existir, incluso si mandas llamar nuevamente la función, el objeto `shoppingCart` sigue sin existir hasta llegar a la línea donde la declaras

Comment: Ah ok. Pero es un objeto de Storage, la variable deja de existir; pero queda la sesión almacenada. ¿Se puede recuperar este espacio?

Comment: ¿Y si muestras el código completo?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quiere es Guardar un `object` en `localStorage` y obtenerlo luego Pruebe lo siguiente:

cree el `object`

```
var shoppingCart = {
  'p1' : 'jugo',
  'p2' : 'papas',
  'p3' : 'cerveza'
};
```

Guardelo como una cadena en `localStorage`:

```
//localStorage.nombredevariable.
localStorage.shoppingCart = JSON.stringify(shoppingCart);
```

Para obtenerlo, solo lo llama por el nombre con el que lo creo y lo `parsea` para que le quede como objeto nuevamente:

```
var datosShopping = JSON.parse(localStorage.shoppingCart);
```